# Laravel Route request

Tags: laravel

I have make the notifications. but Notifications send perfectly.When I click notification not gone to the Notification for more details.
Route issue

```
 <a href="{{URL::to("surveys/59")}}">
                            <li class="list-group-item notifictionhover">
                                <strong>{{$notification["data"]["fromuser"]["name"]}}</strong>
                                Commented On Survey <strong>{{$notification["data"]["survey"]["title"]}}</strong>
                                <strong>{{$notification["data"]["comment"]["text"]}}</strong>
                                <div>{{$notification["created_at"]}}</div>
                            </li>
                        </a>
```

My Web.php Route define

```
Route::resource("surveys","SurveyController");
```

Comment: Please display all routes (php artisan route:list)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Is the 59 referring to the survey id?